# How to fix 'Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined' in angular7?

Tags: angular

Material Validation

Quantity is required

```
    <div *ngIf="quantity.errors.minlength">should be greater than one</div>
```

I expect that the quantity field should validate only integers no decimal and it should be greater than one.

Comment: Hi, can you please share some more code so, that I can help you.

Comment: sounds like `quantity` wasn't declared with a property called `errors`. could you provide more code for some context?

Answer (score 1):

in case of reactive formes you can try this

```
*ngIf="form.get('quantity').hasError('minlength')"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `?`in property binding:

```
<div *ngIf="quantity?.errors.minlength">should be greater than one</div>
```

This won't throw any errors for not having any `errors` on quantity. and when any errors are bound to quantity the message will show up.